# Data View Web Part (DVWP) for different groups

Tags: 2007, web-part, list, sharepoint-designer

Here is my scenario:

I have three groups, top-level Site Owners and sub-level groups Site Visitors and Site Testers.  I have a single master list of resources with a variety of items stored in it.  What I want to do is create a Data View Web Part for each sub-group, i.e. Site Visitors and Site Testers, such that each group can only view specific data; the data they are allowed to see is based on the content of a specific column, for example Site Testers DVWP will only show the data rows from the master list that contain keyword(s) in the reference column.

The requirement is to create a metadata style permissions scheme similar to [Titus Metadata Security](http://www.titus.com/software/sharepoint/metadata.php).  My questions is, if a specific user is a part of more than one subgroup, i.e. ***user1*** is a member of Site Visitors and Site Testers, can SharePoint merge the DVWPs for each of these subgroups such that ***user1*** can see the content for each of these subgroups?

UPDATE:

I agree Christophe, it will be tricky.  In the master test list I created a column called "Permission", along with 4 row items for testing.  For each row item I specify the name of the group that can see it under the Permission column, i.e. "Testers", "Visitors", etc.  What I'm doing now is creating the DVWPs in SharePoint Designer 2007, I'm leaving the Permission column out so it's not visible to the users of that specific subgroup.  I will upload the DVWPs to my site and assign permissions to each accordingly; so Site Testers see the Testers DVWP, Site Visitors see the Visitors DVWP, etc.  Any user who is a member of both subgroups should see the content visible in both the Testers and Visitors DVWPs.

UPDATE 2:

I was able to setup a DVWP for both Site Testers and Visitors. Users are able to see the items they have access to and are denied access to the source master list as expected.  My only remaining issue is that I want users of a specific sub-group to be able to add items to the source master list from the DVWP, so the master list gets updated with items they add, the list form for that specific sub-group will have the Permission column hard-coded for that subgroup so that specific list item is preset so only users of that specific subgroup, and the Site Owners gropu, can view it.

Answer (score 1):

The Data View Web Part only provides the view, what will decide whether the user sees it or not is the security settings you applied to the list or the item itself.

Permissions in SharePoint are additive. If user1 belongs to both Site Visitors and Site Testers, he/she'll see both the items for Site Visitors and those for Site Testers.

What is not clear is how you plan to assign permissions based on the content of a column. This will certainly be the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many items are in this list, you could use item level permissions on the list, physically securing the content, then use a singular DVWP to display the data as it will all be security trimmed based on the logged in user.

Comment: That's sounds similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm meeting with one of my clients to discuss the Target Audience feature.  Are there other ways of implementing item level permissions.